# UITextfield showing and dismissing very quickly in UIPageViewController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift2, uitextfield, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` as walkthrough presentation for my app. The walkthrough has basically 5 pages in total. Page 4 has a `UITextField` programmatically set. Don't mind the other objects like labels or Images.

The problem I have is that when the user reaches page 4, The user is presented with a Textfield which i'd like the keyboard to show up automatically via a `becomeFirstResponder`.

When I load this 4th view with the textfield, It shows up very quickly on the simulator and on my device and then goes back down. It basically shows up via the `becomeFirstResponder` code but somehow then resigns within 1 second.

I have tried this programmatically and also via the storyboard `UITextfield` to see if that made a difference but both seem to not work.

The code that executes a label is where I also executed the `UITextField` programmatically but for this example, I removed it and used an IBOutlet instead as you can see.

Also, in this `case 3` I would put the `becomeFirstResponder` to activate the keyboard but it still did not work as expected.

Right now I left it in the `viewWillAppear` method as you can see.

Here is my code for this specific scenario:

```
 import UIKit

 class WalkthroughViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var headingLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet var contentLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet var contentImageView:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var pageControl:UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet var forwardButton:UIButton!

// This was added via storyboard via drag and drop

@IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!


// This is a UITextfield programmatically

let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(20, 200.0, 330.0, 40.0)) // x=x-cord, y=y-cord, Width, Height

// May 2 Updates
func textFieldFunc() {


    textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    textField.textColor = UIColor.wetAsphaltColor()
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textField.font  = UIFont(name: "avenir", size: 21)
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words // If you need any capitalization

    textField.becomeFirstResponder()

    self.view.addSubview(textField)

}

func nameLabel() {

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15, 180, 265, 33))
    label.center = CGPointMake(185, 160)
    label.textColor = UIColor.cloudsColor()
    label.font  = UIFont(name: "avenir", size: 30)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "Whats your name?"
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}


@IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Thisis going to handle the name later and it will then reguster the user for later use within the app
}

var index = 0
var heading = ""
var imageFile = ""
var content = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    headingLabel.text = heading
    contentLabel.text = content
    contentImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageFile)
    pageControl.currentPage = index

    // 0...2
    switch index {
    case 0...2: forwardButton.setTitle("NEXT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    nameField.hidden = true

    // 3
    case 3:

        nameLabel()
        nameField.hidden = false

    case 4:
        forwardButton.setTitle("DONE", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    default: break
    }

    print("Index: \(index)")
}

@IBAction func nextButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    switch index {
    case 0...3: // 2
        let pageViewController = parentViewController as! WalkthroughPageViewController
        pageViewController.forward(index)

    case 4: // 3
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "finishedWalkedThrough")
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    default: break
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if nameField.hidden == false {
        nameField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

}

My question is, how can I remedy this so that when the 4th page is presented in a slide through manner, the `UITextfield` can present the keyboard like a normal view?

Comment: pls explain what method forward in pageViewController.forward(index) does. Currently learning UIPageController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I saw in a very similar post, This actually worked. I managed to solve it by using this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if index == 3 {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            let strongSelf: WalkthroughViewController = self
            strongSelf.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        })
    }

 }
```

Now when I scroll to the 4th page (3rd from 0), It loads the keyboard with the `.becomeFirstResponder` as a normal `UITextField` would.

Comment: this method strucks the app, GUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
    let strongSelf: WalkthroughViewController = self
    strongSelf. textField.becomeFirstResponder()
})
```

I didn't have to specify the index position of the ViewController